# I can not seem to save my array entires into my textfile

Tags: c#

I have created an that you enter string inputs 
In an array. Once all the array entries are entered they are then stored in a TeXt file. As well as they must be stored in ascending order
. but I am having trouble in storing in the text file. I have created array and when I enter the name they display in console app in ascending order

Here's the code

```
namespace Sandra2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] storeNames = new string[56];
            string s = "\n";
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
            StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter("C:\\mine\\Output" + time + ".txt");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Authors " + " & " + "Enter Book title");
            File.WriteLine("Authors Name" + " \t   " + " Book Title");


            for (int i = 0; i < storeNames.Length; i++)
            {
                string Author;
                 Author = Console.ReadLine();

                 Array.Sort<String>(storeNames);
                 if (Author == "stop")
                 {
                     break;
                 }
                 storeNames[i] = Author;
                 storeNames[i] += "\n";


                 File.WriteLine(Author.ToString());
                 File.Close();
                 File.WriteLine("\n");
                 File.WriteLine("The names in ascending order are: {0}", s);
                 Console.ReadKey();
            }

            foreach (string num in storeNames)
            {
                s += num;
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow how do I add the code here

Comment: Edit your question, in the box paste your code under your text. You can format it or one of us can edit it and apply formatting.

Comment: I can't seem to add the code I'm new here

Comment: Put it in a sharing site like pastebin.com and post the link here, I'll edit and put it in your question.

Comment: I just pasted it like an answer

Comment: You should not have a `File.Close` and then try to write to the file.

Comment: Ron Boyer its still not working maybe its my directory the way I store my textfile

Comment: You should: 1. Read the data from the user (one loop) 2. Sort the data (outside the loop of #1) 3. Output the data / write to file (`File.WriteAllLines` is simple to use here). Also, why not use a `List<String>` instead of array? Then you only get as many elements as you actually need.